# Common Lisp alternative to using Classes

Tags: class, oop, lisp, common-lisp, clos

I'm wondering how to store a single variable and to have specific functions on that variable. I'm wondering if there are alternatives to creating a class.

Specifically, I am creating an application where I store a value for time that represents the number of seconds elapsed from a base time (e.g., Jan 1, 2000, 00:00:00). I want to perform operations on this value such as convert it from seconds from to a specific time or date, or from a date to the specific seconds.

I have done this using a class, however it seems wasteful. Specifically, every time I access the stored value for seconds elapsed it would look similar to `(time-time time)` where `time-time` is the accessor for the time instance `time`.

Is there a better way to design this, perhaps without classes?

Comment: Why not just store it as an integer?

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to use the [universal time functions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_un.htm) that are part of the standard?

Comment: In order of frequency what do you do with it? Is it a specific time or do you get an elapsed time since your offset?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, I didn't know about the universal time functions. It is very similar to something that I've written. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a class which is just wrapping a single object, and that object has a known type, then you can always just write methods for the class of that object instead:

```
(defmethod time-as-unix-time ((tm integer))
  (- tm (load-time-value (encode-universal-time 0 0 0 1 1 1970 0))))
```

For instance.

Of course object-oriented zealots will throw you into a pit full of spikes if they catch you doing this sort of thing: it no doubt violates encapsulation or some other rule of the cult.

Comment: Can I make the method more restrictive than by type without using classes?

Comment: @audrow Well, you *are* using a class, just a [built in one](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_built_.htm#built-in-class).  You can define any kind of method for a `built-in-class` that you can for any other class: what you can't do is subclass it, and it doesn't have any slots or other attributes other than what the standard defines for it.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Accessor names**

You can name accessors in CLOS any way you like. The accessor function could be called `seconds`:

```
CL-USER 23 > (defclass mytime ()
               ((seconds :accessor seconds :initarg :seconds)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS MYTIME 422015CDD3>

CL-USER 24 > (let ((mt (make-instance 'mytime :seconds 100)))
               (values (seconds mt)
                       (truncate (seconds mt) 60)))
100
1
```

**Shorter access to slots via accessor functions**

Common Lisp also has a form `WITH-ACCESSORS`. It allows us to use a symbol instead of an accessor form in the code - for a certain CLOS object. In the following example we can use `secs` and it looks like a variable in the code, but Common Lisp will make sure that it actually calls the accessor `seconds`. We can write `secs` instead of `(seconds mt)`. Thus it helps to make the enclosed code shorter. Compare the next example with the code above.

```
CL-USER 25 > (let ((mt (make-instance 'mytime :seconds 200)))
               (with-accessors ((secs seconds))
                   mt
                 (values secs (truncate secs 60))))
200
3
```

**Shorter access to slots via `SLOT-VALUE`**

CLOS also has `WITH-SLOTS` for slot access via slot names, here the slot named `seconds` of the `mytime` instance can be accessed via the name `secs`:

```
CL-USER 26 > (let ((mt (make-instance 'mytime :seconds 200)))
               (with-slots ((secs seconds))
                   mt
                 (values secs (truncate secs 60))))
200
3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try a closure over a lexical scope like this:

```
(let ((time (get-universal-time)))
  (defun set-time(tm)
    (setf time tm))

  (defun get-time()
    time)

  (defun get-time-in-some-other-format()
    ;; calculate return value based on 'time'
    )
)
```

Comment: You probably wanted that to be `let ((time (get-universal-time))) ...)`?  This is an alternative, but it also makes it so that you only have *one* instance of the time structure.  That might be inconvenient...

Comment: Sorry for the typo, now fixed.

Comment: This is beautiful. I didn't understand how to use closure over a lexical scope before this example. Thank you.